# Jwplayer Customization not work

Tags: jwplayer6

i use jwplayer 6 , i have problem when i want to Customize my player (put skin or autostart option .... ) the player disappear

this code work good :

```
<body>
<div id="player">Loading the player...</div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       jwplayer("player").setup({
           file: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgmXTmj62ic'
       });
   </script>
</body>
```

but when i put something like this the player disappear and show just (Loading the player...) :

```
<body>
        <div id="player">Loading the player...</div>
           <script type="text/javascript">
               jwplayer("player").setup({
                   file: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgmXTmj62ic'
                   autostart: true,
                    mute: true
               });

          </script>
        </body>
```

or if there is any other way to customize player please tell me , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code has error in the 'file' line, try this:

```
<body>
        <div id="player">Loading the player...</div>
           <script type="text/javascript">
               jwplayer("player").setup({
                   file: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgmXTmj62ic',
                   autostart: true,
                    mute: true
               });

          </script>
        </body>
```